# More than one "one to many" association using Detached Criteria (XML Based Hibernate Configuration)

Tags: java, hibernate, detachedcriteria, hibernate-onetomany

I am trying to join three tables by using Detached Criteria Class of Hibernate.

I have three tables those are STUDENT,STUDENT_CORRESPOND,STUDENT_COURSES

Primary Keys of tables are

```
**Table Names**            **Primary Keys**

STUDENT                     INQRY_ID

STUDENT_CORRESPOND          STUDENT_CRSP_ID

STUDENT_COURSES             COURSE_CD
```

select *from 
db01.STUDENT 
INNER JOIN db01.STUDENT_CORRESPOND
ON db01.STUDENT.INQRY_ID =db01.STUDENT_CORRESPOND.INQRY_ID
INNER JOIN db01.STUDENT_COURSES 
ON db01.STUDENT_COURSES.COURSE_CD=db01.STUDENT.COURSE_CD

Actual DB results for the above query is 250 in my Database.

I want to achieve the above query by using detached criteria.

In StudentDO.hbm.xml,I have added following code but when I ran my application it's not displaying any results.i.e

the results count is zero.

StudentDO.hbm.xml

```
<set name="StudentIds" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="none" sort="unsorted"
batch-size="10">
<key><column name="INQRY_ID" /></key>
<one-to-many class="com.test.StudentCorrespondenceDO"/>
</set>

<set name="coursecodes" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="none" sort="unsorted" batch-size="10">
<key><column name="COURSE_CD"/></key>
<one-to-many class="com.test.StudentCoursesDO"/>
</set>
```

I have added respected setter and getter methods in StudentDO.Java file.

### My Application Main file looks as follows

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria =DetachedCriteria.forClass(StudentDO.class);
detachedCriteria.createCriteria("StudentIds","stuids",Criteria.INNER_JOIN); 
detachedCriteria.createCriteria("coursecodes","coursecds",Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
List l = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(detachedCriteria);
System.out.println(l.size());
```

The result is zero.

```
But When I have coded like this (Only two tables joining ) 
----------------------------------------------------------------------

select *from 
db01.STUDENT 
INNER JOIN db01.STUDENT_CORRESPOND
ON db01.STUDENT.INQRY_ID =db01.STUDENT_CORRESPOND.INQRY_ID
```

Actual DB results count is 10.

I want to achieve the above query by using detached criteria.

StudentDO.hbm.xml

```
<set name="StudentIds" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="none"    sort="unsorted"
batch-size="10">
<key><column name="INQRY_ID" /></key>
<one-to-many class="com.test.StudentCorrespondenceDO"/>
</set>
```

I have added respected setter and getter methods in StudentDO.Java file.
when I ran my application it's displaying correct results. that is 10

### My Application Main file looks as follows for two tables

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria =DetachedCriteria.forClass(StudentDO.class);
detachedCriteria.createCriteria("StudentIds","stuids",Criteria.INNER_JOIN); 
List l = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(detachedCriteria);
System.out.println(l.size());
```

As,I mentioned that Joins of Two tables working fine.But Three tables Joining is not working.
Please could any one provide the solution for my problem.It would be a great helpful from your side.

Thanks a lot.